Problem with emojis and stickers not buffering
So I created a code for my bot to be able to fetch all emojis from the old server to the new server, some as well the stickers, and it does not whether the part if they are boosted or not. This is the code I created.
const getStream = require('get-stream');

const sourceGuildId = 'sourceguildid';
const targetGuildId = 'targetguildid';
const adminRoleId = 'adminroleid';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!transfer_all') {
    try {
      const sourceGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(sourceGuildId);
      const targetGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(targetGuildId);

      const emojis = await sourceGuild.emojis.fetch();
      console.log(`Fetched ${emojis.size} emojis from source guild`);

      const stickers = await sourceGuild.stickers.fetch();
      console.log(`Fetched ${stickers.size} stickers from source guild`);

      for (const emoji of emojis.values()) {
        const emojiURL = emoji.url;  // Use emoji.url directly as emoji.imageURL() may not exist

        const response = await fetch(emojiURL);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Failed to fetch emoji: ${emojiURL}. Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const buffer = await response.buffer();
        const image = await jimp.read(buffer);
        const sendedImage = await image.getBufferAsync(jimp.MIME_PNG);

        await targetGuild.emojis.create(sendedImage, { name: emoji.name, reason: 'Copying emoji' });
        console.log(`Transferred emoji: ${emoji.name}`);
      }

      for (const sticker of stickers.values()) {
        const stickerURL = sticker.url;  // Use sticker.url directly as sticker.imageURL() may not exist

        const response = await fetch(stickerURL);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Failed to fetch sticker: ${stickerURL}. Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const buffer = await response.buffer();
        const image = await jimp.read(buffer);
        const sendedImage = await image.getBufferAsync(jimp.MIME_PNG);

        await targetGuild.stickers.create(sendedImage, { name: sticker.name, reason: 'Copying sticker' });
        console.log(`Transferred sticker: ${sticker.name}`);
      }

      console.log('Emojis and stickers transferred successfully!');
      message.channel.send('Emojis and stickers transferred successfully!');

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while transferring emojis and stickers:', error);
      message.channel.send('Failed to transfer emojis and stickers. Check console for errors.');
    }
  }
});

The problem I am encountering is given below:
Fetched 319 emojis from source guild
Fetched 22 stickers from source guild
Error while transferring emojis and stickers: TypeError [ReqResourceType]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.
    at GuildEmojiManager.create (C:\Users\\Desktop\\\\\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildEmojiManager.js:54:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\\Discord_Projects_Made_By\\\\index1.js:1100:9) lid Error while transferring emojis and stickers: TypeError [ReqResourceType]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.
    at GuildEmojiManager.create (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discord_Projects_Made_By\\System3mLatest\\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildEmojiManager.js:54:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ramyo\Desktop\Discord_Projects_Made_By\\\index1.js:1100:9) {
  code: 'ReqResourceType'
}

I tried to use ArrayBuffer() or even other responses. Buffers like clonse().buffer() yet didn't work, because I am just encountering the problem when I want to buffer the gif or the image. That's the issue I am having.
